# Qt Creator/Designer Program Doesn't Show?

Tags: python, qt

I have created a simple test program in Qt Designer that allows you to select a folder and display its contents on a window. It looks like this:

[image: Simple Test Program]

I have successfully converted the `.ui` file to `.py` without fail. Next, here is my code to run the program, aptly named `main.py`:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
import sys
import design
import os

class ExampleApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
def _init_(self):
    super(self._class_, self)._init_()
    self.setupUI(self)
    self.btnBrowse.clicked.connect(self.browse_folder)

def browse_folder(self):
    self.listWidget.clear()
    directory = QtGui.QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,"Pick a Folder")

    if directory:
        for file_name in os.listdir(directory):
            self.listWidget.addItem(file_name)

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    form = ExampleApp()
    form.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In my command prompt, I run the following code:

```
python main.py
```

It proceeds to load for a second or two, and then I get this:
[image: Python and Program]

Is there something that I am doing wrong? Why isn't my program showing up the way it should be? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PyQt4 trouble creating a simple GUI application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219367/pyqt4-trouble-creating-a-simple-gui-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These lines are wrong:

```
def _init_(self):
    super(self._class_, self)._init_()
```

Instead you want something like:

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(ExampleApp, self).__init__(parent)
```

Note the double underscores, the different super argument, and passing `parent` to the super class. I can't test this right now, but it should be much closer to working.

By naming your `__init__` method incorrectly it never would've been called. That explains why you get a window but not the one you designed.

Comment: So, I did that, and I got the following error:

`Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "main.py", line 27, in <module>

      main()

  File "main.py", line 22, in main

      form = ExampleApp()

  File "main.py", line 8, in __init__(parent)

     super(ExampleApp, self).__init__(parent)

 NameError: name 'parent' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry about the code misalignment. I tried spacing it out, and it didn't do it the way I wanted it.

Comment: Did you include the `parent=None` argument?

Comment: Yeah, and then I get this error:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 27, in <module> main() 
File "main.py", line 22, in main form = ExampleApp() 
File "main.py", line 9, in __init__(parent) 
self.setupUI(self) 
AttributeError: 'ExampleApp' object has no attribute 'setupUI'`

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's `setupUi`.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much for all your help, @101.